# Disable columns under certain condition

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I need to disable/enable to input some columns under certain conditions, can I do it with tabulator?
Columns available or locked to input when I open page with table with some state (boolean or etc). Thank you.

example:

```js
//define some sample data
var tabledata = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Oli Bob",
        age: "12",
        col: "red",
        dob: ""
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mary May",
        age: "1",
        col: "blue",
        dob: "14/05/1982"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Christine Lobowski",
        age: "42",
        col: "green",
        dob: "22/05/1982"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Brendon Philips",
        age: "125",
        col: "orange",
        dob: "01/08/1980"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Margret Marmajuke",
        age: "16",
        col: "yellow",
        dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
];

var table_3 = new Tabulator("#table_3", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Name",
            field: "name",
            width: 150,
            editor: "input"
        },
        {
            title: "Age",
            field: "age",
            align: "left",
            formatter: "progress",
            editor: "input"
        },
        {
            title: "Favourite Color",
            field: "col",
            editor: "input"
        },
        {
            title: "Date Of Birth",
            field: "dob",
            sorter: "date",
            align: "center",
        },
    ],
});
```

How can I disable `editor: "input"` under certain conditions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried. Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: I found a solution:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit
"Optional Editing"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to the ***editable***  option in the column definition, it will pass in the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-cell) for the cell being edited.

You can then return `true` to allow the edit, or `false` to reject it:

```
///define editor
var editCheck = function(cell){
    //cell - the cell component for the editable cell

    //get row data
    var data = cell.getRow().getData();

    return data.age > 18; // only allow the name cell to be edited if the age is over 18
}
```

```js
//in your column definition for the column
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", editable:editCheck}
```

Full details can be found in the [Edit Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#optional)